# Python 3 parsing To/From email headers

Tags: python-3.x, email

I'm running Python 3.8.10, and am parsing email header addresses via the email.utils.parseaddr(). It works for most addresses, but found a really simple email header that it parses incorrectly. In the example below notice the name is incorrect as is the email address returned by email.utils.parseaddr()

```
import email.utils

testHdr = "LastName, FirstName <FirstName.LastName@domain.com>"
print("Header=[" + testHdr + "]")
print(str(email.utils.parseaddr(testHdr)))
```

Outputs:

```
Header=[LastName, FirstName <FirstName.LastName@domain.com>]
('', 'LastName')
```

This doesn't seem to be a malformed headers... Am I doing something wrong, or am I using the wrong API?

Answer (score 0):

I found email.utils.parseaddr is depreciated. I rewrote the code using BytesHeaderParser and it resolved the issue.